# Retirar dois valores de um arquivo de texto

Tags: python

Preciso retirar dois números de um arquivo de texto, e adicioná-los a duas variáveis (X e Y).
Estou tentando usar o CSV mas não estou conseguindo.

```py
with open('circulo.plt','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
```

Aqui está um exemplo da tabela:

```
PW0.350,5;
PW0.350,6;
PW0.350,7;
PW0.350,8;
LT;
SP1;
PU-2158 393;
PD-1358 393;
PD-1358 1193;
PD-2158 1193;
PD-2158 393;
SP0;
```

---

Os únicos valores que me interessam são os que começam com "PU-" e "PD-".

Comment: Tente nos mostrar seu código. O que tentou fazer? Como você fez?

Answer (score 1):

O método [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv) retorna um *reader* que você deve usar para iterar pelas linhas do arquivo. Para cada linha, é retornada uma lista contendo os respectivos campos. Como você usou o `delimiter=' '`, os campos serão separados por espaços. Então basta ver se o primeiro elemento da lista começa com "PU-" ou "PD-", usando o método [`startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith):

```
import csv
with open('circulo.plt','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for linha in plots:
        if linha[0].startswith('PU-') or linha[0].startswith('PD-'):
            print(linha)
```

No caso, estou imprimindo a linha inteira. Como cada linha é retornada como uma lista, a saída é:

```
['PU-2158', '393;']
['PD-1358', '393;']
['PD-1358', '1193;']
['PD-2158', '1193;']
['PD-2158', '393;']
```

Aí você decide se vai usar `lista[0]` para pegar somente o primeiro elemento (as strings que começam com "PU-" ou "PD-"), ou `lista[1]` para pegar o respectivo valor ("393;", "1193;", etc).

---

Mas talvez você nem precise usar o módulo `csv`, pois dá para ler as linhas do arquivo assim:

```
with open('/tmp/arq.txt','r') as arquivo:
    for linha in arquivo:
        if linha.startswith('PU-') or linha.startswith('PD-'):
            print(linha.split())
```

A diferença é que agora cada linha é uma string contendo a linha inteira, então eu uso [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) para separar a string por espaços e retornar uma lista. A saída é a mesma do exemplo anterior.

Da mesma forma que a solução anterior, você pode escolher se pega o primeiro ou segundo elemento da lista retornada por `split`.

---

Se quiser, também pode usar expressões regulares, através do [módulo `re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re

r = re.compile(r'^P[UD]-')
with open('/tmp/arq.txt','r') as arquivo:
    for linha in arquivo:
        if r.match(linha):
            print(linha.split())
```

Para cada linha do arquivo, é verificado se ela corresponde à regex `^P[UD]-`.

O [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` significa "início da string", assim eu garanto que vou testar somente se a string começa com determinado padrão.

Em seguida temos a letra `P` maiúscula e logo depois uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (os colchetes). No caso, `[UD]` significa "a letra `U` **ou** a letra `D`". Em seguida, temos o hífen.

Portanto, a regex testa se a linha começa com `PU-` ou `PD-`.

---

Outra opção, para testar a regex e ao mesmo tempo pegar os valores é:

```
import re

r = re.compile(r'^(P[UD]-\S+) (\S+)')
with open('/tmp/arq.txt','r') as arquivo:
    for linha in arquivo:
        m = r.match(linha)
        if m:
            print(m.group(1), m.group(2))
```

Agora estou usando parênteses para formar [grupos de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) - isso permite que eu pegue os valores que a regex encontrou. Também uso o [atalho `\S`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-31), que significa "qualquer caractere que não seja espaço" (veja a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-30) para saber todos os caracteres que são considerados "espaços" - isso inclui o <kbd>TAB</kbd> e quebras de linha, por exemplo).

Em seguida eu uso `group(1)` e `group(2)` para obter os valores obtidos por cada par de parênteses. O primeiro grupo é a string que começa com "PD-" ou "PU-", e o segundo grupo é a string que vem logo em seguida no arquivo. A saída, neste caso, são duas strings diferentes, em vez de uma lista:

```
PU-2158 393;
PD-1358 393;
PD-1358 1193;
PD-2158 1193;
PD-2158 393;
```

Comment: Excelente explicação. Tava tentando usar regex mais me perdi no meio.